# Using the ngx-echarts directives for Angular 15 but chartInit isn't returning the full chart instance, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: angular, echarts, ngx-echarts

The ec returned from

```
<div
  echarts
  [options]="chartOptions || defaultOptions"
  (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)"
></div>
```

example-chart.component.ts

```
export class ExampleChartComponent {
  @Input() chartOptions!: EChartsOption;

  initOpts = {
    renderer: 'svg',
    width: 608,
    height: 302,
  };

  defaultOptions = DefaultOptions as EChartsOption;

  onChartInit(chartInstance: any) {
    console.log(chartInstance);
  }
}
```

console logs out as:

```
id: "ec_1687258340364"
resize: ƒ ()
_$eventProcessor: ECEventProcessor {}
__ec_primitive__: true
__flagInMainProcess: false
__pendingUpdate: null
_api: class_1 {getDom: ƒ, getZr: ƒ, getWidth: ƒ, getHeight: ƒ, getDevicePixelRatio: ƒ, …}
_chartsMap: {_ec_series00_series.line: LineView, _ec_series10_series.line: LineView, 
...etc
```

where _api has the method I want (getOption()) but isn't really "available" to be executed.